# Prove that $\overline{A}\cup \mathring{D}=\mathring{(A\cup\overline{D})}=X$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

I want to prove that if $X$ is a topological space and $A, D, \subset X$ are so that $A\cup D=X$, then:
$$\overline{A}\cup \mathring{D}=\mathring{(A\cup\overline{D})}=X$$
I am a bit lost here. To do this kind of proofs I usually take $x\in$ LHS and try to see that it also belongs to RHS, and then do the opposite process.
However this doesn't seem viable here since there are too many cases; I would have to prove $4$ inclusions  and also I would have to distinguish several cases inside each inclusion (e.g. if $x \in \overline{A}\cup \mathring{D}$ then $x \in \overline{A}$ or $x \in \mathring{D}$ or $x \in \overline{A}$ and $x \in \mathring{D}$). Plus I don't know how to manage some of this cases.
Can someone help me prove this?

Comment: How are you defining closure and interior? Largest containing closed set and smallest contained open set, respectively?

Comment: @angryavian that's exactly it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A$; clearly $U$ is open, and $U\subseteq X\setminus A\subseteq D$, so $U\subseteq\operatorname{int}D$. Thus, $X\supseteq(\operatorname{cl}A)\cup\operatorname{int}D\supseteq(\operatorname{cl}A)\cup U=X$, and therefore $(\operatorname{cl}A)\cup\operatorname{int}D=X$.

It remains to show that $\operatorname{int}(A\cup\operatorname{cl}D)=X$. Reversing the rôles of $A$ and $D$ in the previous argument, we see that $(\operatorname{int}A)\cup\operatorname{cl}D=X$, and $\operatorname{int}A\subseteq A$, so $A\cup\operatorname{cl}D=X$. Finally, $X$ is open, so $X$ is its own interior, and therefore $\operatorname{int}(A\cup\operatorname{cl}D)=X$.